# How do I find out the JRE default linger-on-close time out value?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

According to the Apache HTTP Client [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/params/HttpConnectionParams.html#getLinger%28org.apache.http.params.HttpParams%29) (for Android), a linger-on-close value of -1 for an HTTPConnection implies that the JRE default value is used. How do I find this JRE default value? I looked in the System Properties but could not find it. Here's the code I used:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.list(System.out);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. The following code demonstrates how I found out the JRE default value.

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
        int linger = -2;//To distinguish the "initial value"
        try {
            linger = socket.getSoLinger();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Socket.getLinger() = "+linger);
```

A value of -1 here implies that [linger is *disabled*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getSoLinger%28%29).